# weird error in php and mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM playerlocations WHERE player<>'0'");

$returntext="";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($returntext!=""){$returntext.="&";}
$returntext.=$row['player']."#".$row['locations'];
}
```

the error message claims that $result isn't a valid result set. I tested it in phpmyadmin, and it worked. I don't know why it won't work here, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it isn't a valid **result set**.  That doesn't necessarily mean it isn't a valid **query**.  (Although `!=` instead of `<>` would be nice.)

To figure out why it's not valid, output the result of calling `mysql_error()` after running the query:

```
echo mysql_error(); //most direct way to do this
```

It will tell you what MySQL reports as the error message.

One obvious thing to check: have you opened the connection (with `mysql_connecst()`) before running the query?

Comment: wait... no, that wasn't the issue, its that i forgot to give my user perms for the DB...